# Filter nested collections using Rxjs

Tags: javascript, filter, rxjs, observable, reactive

I need to filter the following json data structure using Rxjs operators,

consider the following example, we have list of hotels and each hotel as rooms underneath it, we need to get all hotels that have available rooms in it,

so consider the following input as:

```js
var hotels = [
   {
       "hotel": "hotel 1",
       "rooms": [
           {
               "name": "room 1",
               "flexible": true
           },
           {
               "name": "room 2",
               "flexible": false
           }
       ]
   },
   {
       "hotel": "hotel 2",
       "rooms": [
           {
               "name": "room 1",
               "flexible": false
           },
           {
               "name": "room 2",
               "flexible": false
           }
       ]
   }
];
```

and the desired output should be as the following:

```js
 var availableRooms = [
       {
           "hotel": "hotel 1",
           "rooms": [
               {
                   "name": "room 1",
                   "flexible": true
               }
           ]
       }    
  ];
```

so How can I apply this in Rxjs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that we need a RxJx?

```
function isAvailable(room) { return room.flexible };
hotels
  .map(hotel => ({ ...hotel, rooms: hotel.rooms.filter(isAvailable) }))
  .filter(hotel => hotel.rooms.length);
```

If `hotel` goes one by one - then use the same approach but with RxJs operators.

**Edited**
Solution with RxJS

```
function isAvailable(room) { return room.flexible };
from(hotels).pipe(
  map(hotel => ({ ...hotel, rooms: hotel.rooms.filter(isAvailable) })),
  filter(hotel => hotel.rooms.length),
  toArray(),
).subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: @Amr_Abdelkader the `from` observable pushes the hotel one by one into your subscriber. If you want to take the result at once you have to use `of`

Comment: @Buggy Thanks a lot .. that's exactly what I wanted